# Piston leaked 1 cup of alcohol in 1 hr

Tags: piston, cylinder-leakdown

I am analyzing a cylinder [leakdown across all 6 cylinders of about 90% in each cylinder](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88384/likelihood-of-every-piston-ring-corroding-the-same-rate).  After repeatedly confirming it wasn't the valves or the head gasket, I removed one of the heads and poured 1 cup of isopropyl alcohol in two cylinders, to test piston rings. Both cylinders leaked out the whole amount of alcohol in 1 hr.

Does this confirm that my piston rings are leaking or is this a normal amount of leakage through a healthy piston? I do not have a healthy cylinder for comparison, they are all leaking the same amount.

Comment: No. It confirms you have ring gap.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- I am sorry, can you be more specific? Are you saying (1) that this does not confirm leaky piston rings (piston rings could still be fine) or (2) the piston rings are definitely blown and need replacement ?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- are you saying this loss of a cup of alcohol is normal for any piston, due to a gap in the ring(s)?

Comment: Correct, it does NOT confirm you have leaky piston rings. It doesn't disprove it, either. IPA is very thin. It can easily leak past the rings via a ring gap. If you have completely proven the valves are good, it could be the rings haven't or aren't completely seated ... at least that's about the only other thing it might be by my way of thinking.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 -- is it a tenable hypothesis that, over the two months or so the heads were off, while the deck was open and only covered with the hood, the rings somehow "unseated" themselves? Can I fix that without taking the pistons out?

Comment: Were the rings ever seated in the first place? At this point I think your best bet is to remove everything, re-hone the cylinders, check your ring gap, clean everything meticulously, then start putting it back together. I don't think you're going to be able to figure out if this is the problem or if you have a different problem without doing that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135604/discussion-between-amphibient-and-ps2).