# Piston Ring Replacement Checklist

Tags: piston

I confirmed that my piston rings were leaking after moisture got in and corroded them when I had the heads off. It's a 2007 Toyota Tacoma V6 4L. I took the diff and oil pan off, sent air through spark plug holes and confirmed it was coming from the bottom of the cylinder.

So I am taking each piston out and replacing rings. What is a routine checklist (measurements) and maybe machining (coating?) of each piston that I should perform? Or can I expect that standard rings should fit (one size fits all)?

RELATED: [Likelihood of every piston ring corroding the same rate](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88384/likelihood-of-every-piston-ring-corroding-the-same-rate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot "assume" you can use standard rings. If you want to do it right, you need to measure the cylinder bore to see if you can use them or if you should bore the cylinder. There is a tolerance with every engine set by the manufacturer as to what is "out of tolerance". You can usually find these specs in a Haynes manual or the like. You also need to measure your cylinder for taper (top to bottom) as well as for out of round. Each of these will have a tolerance as well. You also need to check the piston itself for wear. You may have rust scoring on the cylinders, which would need to be taken care of (usually by boring the cylinders). If you have to bore the cylinders, you'll need new pistons as well. Pistons have a measurement check on them. You'd need to use a micrometer, usually at the top of the skirt. The portion of the skirt which is on the thrust side of the piston usually gets the most wear. Again, these specifications can be found either online or in a rebuild manual like Haynes puts out.

All that said, you may be able to get by with a re-ring and honing the cylinder walls. This would be the *bare minimum* you'd need to do to replace the rings. In order to do this, you have to tear the engine apart. It only makes sense to put new bearings in while you're at it.

Comment: for honing, should I use a tool that looks like [this](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61WkVaKzhRL._AC_SL1500_.jpg) or like [this](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/11RNNX9W0wL.jpg)?

Comment: @amphibient - Either will work. The ball hone (dingleberry hone) will do the better job, though. Trade off is, they are a lot more expensive. Either way, the key to getting the hone done is to ensure movement of the hone up and down in the bore (don't dwell). This creates the cross-hatch in the cylinder. Why do you want to hone in the first place? If you replace the rings and don't, the rings won't seat and you'll have blowby and loss of compression. Don't over do the honing, either. Keep passes equal between bores (IE: 10 passes each cyl).

Comment: https://youtu.be/f7JuMGsyDAg - This video talks about the regular hone, but the process is pretty much the same.

Comment: you think it's OK to keep the crankshaft in while honing? because i don't need to take it out to remove the pistons

Comment: Absolutely not a good idea. The stone grit goes all over the place. It will get into all the nooks/crannies. You have to thoroughly clean the block after honing.

Comment: is it like that with both kinds of honing tools?

Comment: Yes. Both leave grit behind. It's how it does it's thing. The grit grinds on the smooth surface of the cylinder to get the surface finish you need so the new rings will seat. This action leaves grit behind.

Comment: sorry, one more question: when measuring the exact diameter of a cylinder/piston, how to do I make sure the caliper is positioned exactly on the diameter span and not e.g. slightly off? because each 1000th of an inch should count, no?

Comment: Yes, every 1000th of an inch counts. There is one of two ways to accurately measure the bore: 1) with a [dial bore gage](https://www.amazon.com/Fowler-Warranty-52-646-500-0-Measuring-Graduation/dp/B00B5HJWYW/), being set from a [micrometer](https://www.amazon.com/Outside-Micrometer-Graduation-Standards-Ratchet/dp/B07M8556GG/); 2) inside [snap gage](https://www.amazon.com/AccusizeTools-Pcs-Telescoping-Gage-EG02-5011/dp/B019EJ0OHQ/) to get the size, then using a micrometer to measure it.

Comment: so the obvious (economy) choice of a DIYer would be the snap gauge. is it less accurate?

Comment: but i can see how a snap gauge can miss the exact diameter the same way as if I only used a caliper

Comment: Actually, used correctly, the snap gage is pretty accurate. The ends are rounded, so they find the broadest point of the cylinder automatically. The real difference between the snap gage and the dial bore gage is the dial bore gage you set once and you can measure everything in the bore very easily. With a snap gage, you have to do your measurements one at a time. Done correctly, either method gives you the information you need.

Comment: "measure everything in the bore very easily" -- what else is there to measure except for the diameter?

Comment: It's just the diameter. To do it right, though, you need to measure it for out of round, which requires two measurements 90° from each other, at the top, middle, & bottom of each cylinder. Once a dial bore gage is set, you're measuring how far out from your desired measurement you are. It's just really easy to get your measurements that way.